# Regarding my offer letter

Tags: professionalism, job-offer, india

I am a fresher and I have received an offer letter but it is not in pdf or doc format and it is simply through a mail. What I should do in this case??  Can an offer letter be a mail only?? Is it valuable??I am from India.

Answer (score 3):

While it's usual that official documents are sent in PDF, it's not unheard of email-only document / communication. It may very well be the case that this is a tentative / provisional offer letter and once you accept these terms and conditions, they'll provide you with a properly formatted letter (with company letterhead etc).

You should do following things:

- Ensure the email is from the official mail ID of the company and not someone's personal mail (yahoo, gmail, rediff, hotmail etc).
- Respond to the email and let them know your acceptance (or rejection, as applicable).
- Ask them about the possibility of getting a formal copy (printed, or in PDF).

However, this is usually not a very big deal and emails are perfectly acceptable ways of communication.

Comment: Not sure if OP meant email or physical mail.

Comment: @jcm True that, but physical mail will have printed copy anyways, eliminating the need of a PDF (which is considered a primary substitute of the printed version). I believe OP's problem is, instead of a PDF, the offer in written in the body of the email.